# how to refresh user control in C# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I use user control instead of form in C# winform. in user control , i put button(New) when click button , user control is refreshed. 
i use this.refresh(); in event but isn't worked!

```
private void Btn_New_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean isnt worked?

Comment: in my user control , i put combobox and 2 text box, when change selected item in combo,textbox.text start with 1 or 2 or 3.and user add number in textbox and when clicked btnNew , must clear textbox and return to previous state, but didn,t worked

Comment: To get a better answer you should provide more code. This helps you better explain your situation.

Answer (score 1):

`Refresh()` just repaints the control on the screen. Normally you would not call it manually instead you must change the properties of controls like

```
private void Btn_New_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TextBoxFirstName.Text = string.Empty;
    this.TextBoxLastName.Text = string.Empty;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i didn't want to text of textbox is cleared. because combo box is selected.

Comment: As Knaģis has mentioned, the Refresh method is just a re-painting of the control. If you dont want your text boxes to be clear, you can write whatever code you want to modify your text boxes or combo boxes, but you must write the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement 2 Methods, one for managing the combobox and other for managing the Button.

```
Private Void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged ()
{
     switch(ComboBox.selectedIndex)
     {
          case 0:
               textbox1.text = "1";
               break;
          case 1:
               textbox1.text = "2";
               break;
          // ... etc
     }
}

Private Void Button_clicked ()
{
     ComboBox.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```